# Keras crossentropy

Tags: python, keras

I'm working with Keras and I'm trying to rewrite categorical_crossentropy by using the Keras abstract backend, but I'm stuck.

This is my custom function, I want just the weighted sum of crossentropy:

```
def custom_entropy( y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred /= K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

    # clip to prevent NaN's and Inf's
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())

   loss = y_true * K.log(y_pred) 
   loss = -K.sum(loss, -1)

   return loss
```

In my program I generate a `label_pred` with to `model.predict()`.

Finally I do:

```
    label_pred = model.predict(mfsc_train[:,:,5])
    cc = custom_entropy(label, label_pred)
    ce = K.categorical_crossentropy(label, label_pred)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SAMME_train_all.py", line 47, in <module>
    ce = K.categorical_crossentropy(label, label_pred)
  File "C:\Users\gionata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib
s\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2754, in categorical_c
    axis=len(output.get_shape()) - 1,
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

Comment: Maybe you could tell us how you want it to be calculated instead?

Comment: i edited the previous messagge with my custom_loss
i tried to test both, calling them with the same parameters (and prob=np.ones()) but the basic crossentropy gives me an error : no getShape

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keras backend functions such `K.categorical_crossentropy` expect tensors.

It's not obvious from your question what type `label` is. However, we know that `model.predict` always returns NumPy `ndarrays`, so we know `label_pred` is not a tensor. It is easy to convert, e.g. (assuming `label` is already a tensor),

```
custom_entropy(label, K.constant(label_pred))
```

Since the output of this function is a tensor, to actually evaluate it, you'd call

```
K.eval(custom_entropy(label, K.constant(label_pred)))
```

Alternatively, you can just use `model` as an op, and calling it on a tensor results in another tensor, i.e.

```
label_pred = model(K.constant(mfsc_train[:,:,5]))
cc = custom_entropy(label, label_pred)
ce = K.categorical_crossentropy(label, label_pred)
```

Now `label_pred`, `cc` and `ce` will all be tensors.

Answer (score 2):

As given in the [documentation](https://keras.io/losses/#categorical_crossentropy), arguments are tensors:

```
y_true: True labels. TensorFlow/Theano tensor.
y_pred: Predictions. TensorFlow/Theano tensor of the same shape as y_true.
```

Converting numpy arrays to tensors should solve it.